# What is the asymptotic complexity of T(n) = T(n-1) + O(n * n!)?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, time-complexity, factorial

What is the asymptotic complexity of T(n) = T(n-1) + O(n * n!)? A tight upper bound would suffice. I am trying to calculate the time complexity of a very elaborate recursive algorithm to find anagrams and eventually I came up on this formula (which is hopefully right). You can assume that the algorithm stops when it reaches T(1).

Edit: T(n) = T(n-1) + O(n * n!) equals of course O(n*n!) + O((n-1)*(n-1)!) + ... + O(1) but I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: So you have *n*  steps and each step is *O(n * n!)* ?

Comment: @dtb Yes that's true.

Comment: can also be thought of as O((n+2)!)

Comment: @clwhisk How did you find that?

Comment: @Sid by definition of factorial and O notation ((n+2)*(n+1)*n! > n*n*n!), but it's not the tightest upper bound as Novelocrat pointed out

Comment: @millimoose Are you sure that you can say that O((n+1)!) = O(n!)?

Comment: @Sid You're right, that's too much handwaving on my part since it's not a constant factor. The point is moot since you're asking for a tight bound where said handwaving would be inappropriate anyway. (BTW, "upper tight bound" is not a thing - I believe a tight bound is where the same function is both an upper and lower bound for some constant factors *c1* and *c2*.)

Comment: @millimoose The choice of words is from my textbook. I understand your point but I interpret it as a _reasonable_ upper bound. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The other answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18837142/90002 is much better than mine. That user should get the credit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get a rigorous understanding of what's going on, note that

```
n * n! = (n + 1) * n! - n! = (n + 1)! - n!
```

Hence the original function can be rewritten as:

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + c * ((n + 1)! - n!)  where c is a constant from the O(f(n)) notation
```

If you expand T(n-1) etc you'll see that the factorials cancel out giving finally

```
T(n) = T(0) + c * ((n + 1)! - 0!)
```

Hence if T(0) is constant and finite,

```
T(n) = O((n + 1)!)
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that since we have that (n+1)! = (n+1)*n! = n*n! + n! < 2(n*n!), we can say that O((n+1)*n!)=O(n*n!+n!)=O(2(n*n!))=O(n*n!) which is the same answer as Novelocrat gave.

Comment: Yes it should be the same. But the mechanism he used (using a large upper bound on each term) is not necessarily the best way as it could lead to gross over-estimation. He could have as well said `each term is less than (2*n)! and hence the order is O(n*(2*n)!)` which would have been right mathematically but is a looser upper bound. There can be a claim made that the order is n times the average value but that analysis was also missing from the post.

Answer (score 2):

It's O(n*n!). Each of the subsequent terms is a lower-order polynomial dominated by the leading term.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't O(n^n).

Comment: If anything, it's *at least* O(n^(n+1)), since O(n!) is approximated by O(n^n)

Comment: O(n!) is asymptotically less than O(n^n).